# How does one POST a binary file stored locally using php-curl?

Tags: php, post, curl

I wish to issue the following curl request using php-curl:

```
curl "http://www.example.com/" -F "file=@foo.ext"
```

How do I need to set this up in PHP (using curl_init, _setopt, etc.), assuming `foo.ext` lives on the machine from which I'm issuing the request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you'd use

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file' => '@foo.ext'));
```

plus whatever options you need. Relevant docs here: http://php.net/curl_setopt

Comment: Looks like I didn't scour that document closely enough last time I looked. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: The '@' sign should precede the file name, not the parameter name. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#example-4025).

Comment: Right you are, Pang. Can you edit your answer for posterity, Marc?